# Extend Plays SBT "run" task

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I've a Play application and want to extend Plays "run" task. I've tried:

```
run in Compile <<= (run in Compile).dependsOn(myOwnTask)
```

Then "myOwnTask" is executed on "play run" and "play start" too, but my task should only be executed on "play run", not in "play start".

I tried to use the PlayRunHook. This works, but then I've no SBT task and sometimes I need to run the task via "sbt myOwnTask".

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> my task should only be executed on "play run", not in "play start".

You'd like the task to be invoked depending on what user command was issued, rather than whether or not "run" is about to be invoked?

You can't make your task a dependency of "run", then.

How about making adding a new "command" which invokes your task and then invokes "run" and asking your users to call that instead of the underlying "run"?